# Reverse Item using dplyr case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, case

I try to reverse an item using dyplr case_when

```
data<- data%>%
  mutate(unhappy_rev = case_when(
    unhappy == 1 ~ 5,
    unhappy == 2 ~ 4,
    unhappy == 3 ~ 3,
    unhappy == 4 ~ 2,
    unhappy == 5 ~ 1))
```

I got this response:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `unhappy_rev = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Failed to evaluate the left-hand side of formula 1.
Caused by error in `vec_equal()`:
! Can't combine `..1` <haven_labelled> and `..2` <double>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: It would be of great help if you could post some reproducible data that exactly mimics your data so that the community can try for themselves to see where the error comes from. See also https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4385980-ask-a-question

Comment: The error message tells you that you are trying to compare vectors of two different data types: "haven_labelled" and "double". Your variable "unhappy" is probably not of the wrong data type. You should try to convert it to numeric first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for your purpose

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(unhappy_rev = 6 - unhappy)
```